# Dependency Between the Twitter Credentials and Bitly credential

Tags: ipad, twitter, sharekit

I am using the ShareKit to share the articles in Twitter. For shortening the URL in Twitter sharing, I am using the Bitly.  Can I use the same Bitly credentials for different Twitter App Key in ShareKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to.

I've only ever created one set of bitly login details and have had no problem shortening URL's!

Matt